# Find 'NaN' characters in a cell array in MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, nan, cell-array

I'm searching for `Nan`'s in `cell array` from an imported `excel file`. After importing the `excel file` to `cell array`, when I double click on `Nan`, in some files i have `Char` and in other imported excel files i have `Double` cells that storing `NaN`. For `double` version i don't have any problem, I will use this function :

```
Out = (cellfun(@(x) any(isnan(x)),cell_array))
```

But if i use this function for `Char` `Nan`s, i can't find any `Nan`. all `Out` values are zero.

What is the problem and how can i solve it?

Comment: For the chars, if I've underfstood correctly, maybe this works: `Out = (cellfun(@(x) any(all(x=='NaN')),cell_array))`?

Comment: I would suggest `Out = (cellfun(@(x) any(strcmp(lower(x),'nan')),cell_array))`.

Comment: Thank you for your fast replies. that's true. please add it to answers but why in some imported excel files i have this effect? what is different in these files?

Comment: @user2991243 one reason I could think of ist that in those files you have excel choose its own column type. For example you can force excel to take that column/cell (in excel) as a number, as a text and so on. It could be that the "smart" excel is sometimes mistaken those NaN's as words instead of a symbolic number. This could be, because you use words, names,etc in the same column. It could be because of casesensity. Or so on. If you want to check it, enter those excel sheets and check what kind of celltype those NaN's are in and how they are written.

Comment: Please add your answers :-) .